# SQL query SUM of SUM's of multiplied columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get sum of calculated columns and display as separate distinct rows (ItemCode) but with no success. I fell I am close to solution but somehow I stuck again

My query:

```
select 
    I.Itemcode,
    Cast((POL.Receivedqty) as Int) as QTY,
    Cast(SUM(POL.Receivedqty * POL.RW_CostPrice) as Money) as TotalVolumexBuyPrice,
    Cast(SUM(POL.ReceivedQty * POL.ItemPrice) as Money) as TotalVolumexCPROSellPrice,
    Cast(POL.RW_CostPrice as Money) as LatestCostPrice,
    Cast(POL.ItemPrice as money) as LatestSellPrice,
    Convert(Varchar, max(POL.Completedate), 111) as LastOrderDate
From 
    initem as I 
left join 
    InpurchaseOrderLine as POL on I.ItemID = POL.ItemID
where 
    POL.CompleteDate between '2014-10-01' and '2015-10-01' 
    and I.Itemcode not like '1000015697' 
    and I.Itemcode like '1000001453' or I.Itemcode like '1000019133'
Group by 
    I.ItemCode, POL.ItemPrice, POL.RW_CostPrice, POL.Receivedqty
Order by   
    POL.RW_CostPrice
```

This returns this data:

```
ItemCode    QTY Cost x QTY  Sell x QTY  CostPrice     SellPrice       
1000001453  0   0.00        0.00        794.00          941.37          
1000001453  14  11116.00    13179.18    794.00          941.37          
1000001453  15  11910.00    14120.55    794.00          941.37          
1000001453  20  31760.00    37654.80    794.00          941.37          
1000001453  14  25592.00    26358.36    914.00          941.37          
1000001453  20  73120.00    75309.60    914.00          941.37          
1000001453  30  27420.00    28241.10    914.00          941.37          
1000001453  31  28334.00    29182.47    914.00          941.37          
1000019133  1   39781.90    45232.02    3978.19         4523.202        
1000019133  2   7956.38     9046.404    3978.19         4523.202        
1000019133  1   3978.19     4523.2022   3978.19         4523.2022       
1000019133  0   0.00        0.00        3978.19         4523.21         
1000019133  1   43760.09    49755.31    3978.19         4523.21         
1000019133  2   7956.38     9046.4      3978.19         4523.21         
1000019133  2   7956.38     9408.2658   3978.19         4704.1329       
1000019133  2   8274.64     9408.2658   4137.32         4704.1329
```

But I would like to get something like that(Sum of Sums):

```
ItemCode    QTY Cost x QTY  Sell x QTY
1000001453  238 209252.00   224046.06
1000001933  11  119661.00   136418.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by I.ItemCode, POL.ItemPrice, POL.RW_CostPrice, POL.Receivedqty, when you only need to group by I.ItemCode

Group by I.ItemCode, and then use [aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) to sum all of your corresponding purchase order lines.

```
select 
    I.Itemcode,
    Cast(Sum(POL.Receivedqty) as Int) as QTY,
    Cast(SUM(POL.Receivedqty * POL.RW_CostPrice) as Money) as "Cost x QTY",
    Cast(SUM(POL.ReceivedQty * POL.ItemPrice) as Money) as "Sell x QTY"
From 
    initem as I 
left join 
    InpurchaseOrderLine as POL on POL.ItemID = I.ItemID
where 
    POL.CompleteDate between '2014-10-01' and '2015-10-01' 
    and I.Itemcode not like '1000015697' 
    and I.Itemcode like '1000001453' or I.Itemcode like '1000019133'
Group by 
    I.ItemCode
```

Comment: Thanks Brino, that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT I.Itemcode,
    Cast((POL.Receivedqty)as Int) as QTY,
    Cast(SUM(POL.Receivedqty*POL.RW_CostPrice)as Money) as TotalVolumexBuyPrice,
    Cast(SUM(POL.ReceivedQty*POL.ItemPrice)as Money) as TotalVolumexCPROSellPrice,
    Cast(POL.RW_CostPrice as Money)as LatestCostPrice,
    Cast(POL.ItemPrice as money) as LatestSellPrice,
    Convert(Varchar,max(POL.Completedate),111) as LastOrderDate
  FROM initem AS I 
  LEFT JOIN InpurchaseOrderLine AS POL 
    ON I.ItemID=POL.ItemID
  WHERE POL.CompleteDate BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND  '2015-10-01' 
    AND I.Itemcode NOT LIKE '1000015697' 
    AND (I.Itemcode LIKE '1000001453' 
         OR I.Itemcode LIKE '1000019133')
  GROUP BY I.ItemCode, POL.ItemPrice, POL.RW_CostPrice, POL.Receivedqty
)
SELECT Itemcode,
   QTY = SUM(Qty),
   [Cost x QTY] = SUM(TotalVolumexBuyPrice)
   [Cost x QTY] = SUM(TotalVolumexCPROSellPrice)
FROM cte
GROUP BY Itemcode
ORDER BY Itemcode;
```

Comment: lad2025 Unfortunately "With" did not work properly as result showed me: